# generating core data properties when create nsmanagedobject subclass

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm trying to create a model for CoreData.

I'm selecting MyCoreData.xcdatamodelId, select the entity... go to `Editor > Create NSManagedObjectSubclass`...I'm selecting the right entity. The issue is that it generates the 4 files:

- `MyModel.h`
- `MyModel.m`
- `MyModel+CoreDataPropeties.h`
- `MyModel+CoreDataPropeties.m`

Why's that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreData create this in order to separate the properties and the functions. This way, you can modify your model and regenerate the class, modifying only MyModel+CoreDataProperties.h/.m and keeping untouch all your fuctions.

Comment: And when I want to use the object I import MyModel+CoreDataPropeties.h, right?

Comment: No, you have to import MyModel.h. You can see it better in Swift than in ObjC. In Swift, MyModel+Core... is an extension of the MyModel class